# Creating data list of specific range from new Workbooks in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've built some code that gets data from various sources and calculate the value of monthly bonus. The code below is used to save each iteration of process (for certain employee) as a new workbook.

```
Sub CopyWorkbook()
 
Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
name = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("calculate").Range("H7") & ".xlsx"
ThisFile = ActiveWorkbook.Path
 
 
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   sh.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
  
Next sh

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisFile & "\" & name, FileFormat _
        :=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close
 
End Sub
```

What I need is creating the list (as a new, separate workbook) of specific pair of values from workbooks created with a loop. For simplify - let's say I'm looking for values of A1,A2 from every workbook that's been created during iteration.

Do you guys have some ideas?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: " from workbooks created with a loop" do you mean " from work*sheets* created with a loop" ?  Where should that list be created?

Comment: There’s one workbook that is kind of calculator for bonus. This calculator iterates over list of employees and calculate bonus for iterated one and save it to another workbook like “<employee name>_ bonus”. I need to have separate workbook that stores bonuses for all emloyees for whom the bonus was calculated. I hope it’s more clear now :)